# I can't upgrade Laravel to version 7 because composer throws errors

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to upgrade Laravel from version 6 to version 7. I've tried different combinations of packages but nothing seems to resolve my errors.

Here is my composer.json (that doesn't work)

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "jgrossi/corcel": "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0",
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/Console/Commands",
            "app/Models",
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

When I run `composer update`, I get this error:

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v6.18.15, required as ^7.0) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.18.15] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.20.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.19.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.19.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.18.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.17.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.17.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.17.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.16.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.16.0
```

That goes on for quite a bit but it seems there are just combinations of packages that don't work together. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Whats your php version?

Comment: PHP Version is 7.4.2

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in [Laravel upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade)

> PHP 7.2.5 Required
>
> Update your `laravel/framework` dependency to `^7.0` in your `composer.json`
> file. In addition, update your `nunomaduro/collision` dependency to
> `^4.1`, `phpunit/phpunit` dependency to `^8.5`, `laravel/tinker` dependency to
> `^2.0`, and `facade/ignition` to `^2.0`.
> The following first-party packages have new major releases to support
> Laravel 7. If there are any, read through their individual upgrade
> guides before upgrading:
>
> ```
> Browser Kit Testing v6.0
> Envoy v2.0
> Horizon v4.0
> Nova v3.0
> Scout v8.0
> Telescope v3.0
> Tinker v2.0
> UI v2.0 (No changes necessary)
> ```
>
> Finally, examine any other third-party packages consumed by your
> application and verify you are using the proper version for Laravel 7
> support.

please follow this [official guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade) and it will be successfully upgrading your laravel version